# Incompatible types in web service java

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
public boolean operation(@WebParam(name = "id") int id,
        @WebParam(name = "nombre") String nombre,
        @WebParam(name = "apellido") String apellido,
        @WebParam(name = "edad") int edad,
        @WebParam(name = "ciclo") int ciclo,
        @WebParam(name = "carrera") String carrera,
        @WebParam(name = "especializacion") String especializacion) {

    WebServiceapp object = new WebServiceapp();
    boolean estado;
    estado = object.getWebServiceappSoap().insertar(id, nombre, carrera,
            edad, ciclo, carrera, nombre);
    return estado;
}
```

But I get an error `incompatible types required boolean found void` on this line:

```
estado = object.getWebServiceappSoap().insertar(id, nombre, carrera,
        edad, ciclo, carrera, nombre);
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please show the method signature of `insertar`...

Comment: Seems that `insertar` returns void

Comment: Which is the signature of the insertar method?

Comment: What is the return value of the insertar method? if it's void then thats your problem

Comment: Maybe you changed the `insertar` method to return a `boolean` and this is in another component that you have to update (recompile) in order to see the changes reflected in your component that holds the `SomeWSClass#operation` method.